# When flatness of $S$ over $R_i$ implies flatness of $S$ over the ring generated by $R_1,R_2$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, flatness

The following question I have asked in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3540862/when-flatness-of-s-over-r-i-implies-flatness-of-s-over-the-ring-generated?noredirect=1&lq=1), but have not received an answer, so I ask it here; I really apologize if it is not suitable for MO.

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $R_1,R_2,S$ be three commutative $k$-algebras with $R_1 \subseteq S$ and $R_2 \subseteq S$.
Assume that $S$ is flat over $R_1$ and also $S$ is flat over $R_2$.

Denote by [$R$](http://www.mathreference.com/ring-alg,compos.html) the ring generated by $R_1$ and $R_2$. Of course, $R$ is a subring of $S$.

> Are there conditions that will guarantee flatness of $S$ over $R$?

**Example 1:** $R_1=k[x], R_2=k[y], R=k[x,y], S=k[x,y,z]$;
$k[x,y,z]$ is free over $k[x]$ and over $k[y]$, hence flat over $k[x]$ and over $k[y]$. Also, $k[x,y,z]$ is free over $k[x,y]$, so it is flat over $k[x,y]$.

However, generally $S$ may not be flat over $R$:

**(Counter)example 2:** $R_1=k[x^2]$, $R_2=k[x^3]$, $R=k[x^2,x^3]$, $S=k[x]$. Clearly, $k[x]$ is free over $k[x^2]$ and over $k[x^3]$, hence flat over $k[x^2]$ and over $k[x^3]$. But $k[x]$ is not flat over $k[x^2,x^3]$.

Notice the difference between the two examples: In the first example $R_1 \cap R_2 =k$, while in the second (counter)example $R_1 \cap R_2=k[x^6] \supsetneq k$.

> Is there another counterexample, but this time with $R_1 \cap R_2=k$?

See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318476/flatness-over-tensor-product) relevant question about flatness over tensor products.

Thank you very much!